# ActiveRecord query for Users who don't own a Car

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

How do I get all the users who do **not** have a car?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I was doing the following:

```
all.select {|user| not user.car }
```

That worked perfect until my database of users and cars got too big and now I get strange errors, especially when I try and sort the result. I need to do the filtering in the query and the ordering as well as part of the query.

***UPDATE***: What I did was the following:

```
where('id not in (?)', Car.pluck(:user_id)).order('first_name, last_name, middle_name')
```

It's fairly slow as Rails has to grab all the `user_id`s from the `cars` table and then issue a giant query. I know I can do a sub-query in SQL, but there must be a better Rails/ActiveRecord way.

***UPDATE 2***: I now have a noticeably more efficient query:

```
includes(:car).where(cars: {id: nil})
```

The answer I accepted below has `joins` with a SQL string instead of `includes`. I don't know if `includes` is more inefficient because it stores the `nil` data in Ruby objects whereas `joins` might not? I like not using strings...

Comment: `includes` doesn't seem correct here.  You should only use `includes` when you actually need to eager-load the association, which is not the case here because that association will always be empty.  If you don't like strings in your relations then you're going to have a bad time with the default `ActiveRecord` syntax.  I would suggest looking at https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel which I use on some side-projects and absolutely love.  `User.joins{car.outer}.where{car.id == nil}` would be your new query with Squeel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a left join from the `users` table to the `cars` table and only take user entries that don't have any corresponding values in the `cars` table, this looks like:

`User.select('users.*').joins('LEFT JOIN cars ON users.id = cars.user_id').where('cars.id IS NULL')`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the work that needs to be done here is SQL.  Try this:

```
User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN cars ON users.id = cars.user_id").where("cars.id IS NULL")
```

It is incredibly inefficient to do this with ruby, as you appear to be trying to do.

You can throw an order on there too:

```
User.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN cars ON users.id = cars.user_id").
  where("cars.id IS NULL").
  order(:first_name, :last_name, :middle_name)
```

You can make this a scope on your `User` model so you only have one place to deal with it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car

  def self.without_cars
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN cars ON users.id = cars.user_id").
    where("cars.id IS NULL").
    order(:first_name, :last_name, :middle_name)
  end
end
```

This way you can do:

```
User.without_cars
```

In your controller or another method, or even chain the scope:

```
User.without_cars.where("users.birthday > ?", 18.years.ago)
```

to find users without cars that are under 18 years old (arbitrary example, but you get the idea).  My point is, this kind of thing should always be made into a scope, so it can be chained with other scopes :)  `Arel` is awesome that way.

Comment: That was down to the second :)

Comment: Haha ya.  We have the same answer :P  I don't think the `select` is necessary. (but I may be wrong)